# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I am playing with Mobx-state-tree.

In a simple model I have built i am getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" .

I am pasting all the code blocks.

Index.js

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./app";
import Invoice from "../models/Invoice"

const invoice = Invoice.create({currency:'EUR'}) ;

ReactDOM.render(<App invoice={invoice}/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

app.Js

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import {observer} from "mobx-react"

class App extends Component
{
    render(){
        const {invoice} = this.props;

        return(
            <div className="container-fluid">Invoicer
            <h1>{invoice.status()} </h1>
            {!invoice.isPaid && <button onClick={invoice.markPaid}>Pay</button>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default observer(App);
```

models / Invoice.js

```
import {types} from "mobx-state-tree";
import ItemList from "./ItemList";

const Invoice  = types.model("Invoice",{
    currency : types.string,
    isPaid:false,
    itemList : types.optional(ItemList,{items:[]})
})
.actions( self => ({
    markPaid(){
     self.isPaid = true;
    }
}))
.views( self => ({

    status(){
        return self.isPaid ? "Paid,Go Home and Enjoy" :"Not Paid,work more and we will think about it";
    }
}));

export default Invoice;
```

ItemList.js

```
import {types} from "mobx-state-tree";
import {Item} from "./Item";

const ItemList = types.model("ItemList",{
    items: types.array(Item)
});

export default ItemList;
```

item.js

```
import {types} from "mobx-state-tree"

const Item = types.model("Item",{
    quantity : types.number,
    price: types.number,
    comodityName: types.string
});

export default Item;
```

There is no error in terminal when compiling with npm. In bundle.js
the error is in this line

```
 array: function(e) {
                return new nt(e.name + "[]",e)
            },
```

I am not sure why this error is occurring ?

Comment: Are you using MobX state tree with MobX 4?

Comment: The versions for mobx: 5.0.3 and mobx-state-tree : 3.0.0

Comment: what is the difference between mobx and MobX ?

Comment: There is no difference. I meant to write MobX 4. MST seems to have added support for MobX 5 now, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: i have a dependency on mobx-react: 5.2.3 . which version of mobx-react should be installed , if mobx 4 version is installed

Comment: I'm not sure. The latest should most likely work.

Comment: can you reproduce this issue i a code sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Skip ItemList and do this

```
itemList : types.optional(types.array(Item, []))
```